# Adding custom rows to contact details, only works with one contact

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts, android-syncadapter, android-account

In an android app, I added a custom row to contact details with a custom `mimetype` to open my app on a specific activity.
It works well if I do it to **one** contact, but if I try to add it to **all** my contacts, the custom row doesn't appear.

I'm using the following code:

```
// TODO Adding multiple inst working
/*contacts.forEach { contact ->
    if (!contact.aliasName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        ContactsManager.instance.addContact(context, contact)
    }
}*/

ContactsManager.addContact(context, contacts[0])
```

---

```
fun addContact(context: Context, contact: Contact) {
    val resolver = context.contentResolver
    resolver.delete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
           ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?", arrayOf(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE))

    val names = contact.name?.split(" ")
    Logger.e(" #### CONTACT Updated", contact.name.toString())

    var givenName = contact.name
    var familyName = ""
    if (names?.size!! > 1) {
       givenName = names[0]
       familyName = names[1]
    }

    val ops = ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>()

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, true))
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_NAME)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE)
            .build())

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Settings.CONTENT_URI, true))
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_NAME)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE)
                .withValue(Settings.UNGROUPED_VISIBLE, 1)
                .build())

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, givenName)
                .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, familyName)
                .build())

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, contact.aliasName.getFormattedPhoneNumber())
                .build())

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1, Integer.valueOf(14))
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA2, context.getString(R.string.transferSummaryActionSendMoney))
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA3, context.getString(R.string.transferSummaryActionSendMoney))
                .build())

        try {
            val results = resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops)
            if (results.isEmpty())
                return
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

**How can I add the custom row to all my contacts?**

Another question that I have is, when I run this code to all my contacts it takes quite some time *(the time between contacts increases by 1 sec between the initial contacts, and about 10 secs when it's reaching the end of the list)*. How can I convert the `applyBatch` to a `bulkInsert`?

Answer (score 1):

well, at the first line of your `addContact` function you're basically deleting all other custom rows your app ever added (`resolver.delete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?", ...)`),

So basically your loop keeps deleting the last row added, and then adding a new row in its place repeatedly...

To fix that, consider adding the specific rawContact ID to the selection of your `resolver.delete` call.

*IMPROVING PERFORMANCE*:

To improve performance of your code you can do two things:

1. move the insert to Settings out of the loop, you probably don't need to repeat that line for each contact
2. have your `addContact` function accept `ops` as a parameter, and only fill it with operations in the function itself, the calling loop should keep checking ops.size and when it increases over some number (try 100) you run `applyBatch`. this should significantly reduce the number of applyBatch calls you're doing, however, there's something tricky here, as you'll need to specify the correct index for RAW_CONTACT_ID, as 0 will point to the first raw contact created in the entire batch, you need to keep track of your created raws, and specify the correct index.